# Using state in server components - Next13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I'm building a simple Next13 lottery app to learn more about the new App Router. I want to fetch data on a server component based on a dynamically-changing piece of state and I am not sure how to accomplish this.

`LottosPage` is a server component that displays a grid of interactive `LottoCard` client components. Following the new Next13 Server Components, it is implemented as an async function that fetches the data on the server:

app/lottos/page.tsx:

```js
export default async function LottosPage() {
  const games: Game[] = await getGames(chainId);

  // process and map games to LottoCards 
}
```

When a user interacts with the `LottoCard`s (e.g. buys a ticket), I refresh the route (using router.refresh()) prompting the `LottosPage` to refetch the data resulting in an update of the games shown. The thing is I want it to fetch different data based on the selected chainId. chainId is selected dynamically in a dropdown in the `layout.tsx` file and I pass it down the component tree using a context provider, this gives all the child components access to its dynamic value using a useContext() hook. The problem is I can't use react hooks in server components. So I am not sure how to access the chainId in `LottosPage`.

So, to summarize, what I want it do is fetch different data based on the selected chainId (as shown in the snippet above). And I want the `LottosPage` to refetch the new data when the selected chainId changes. Is there anyway to accomplish this while keeping `LottosPage` a server component? My intuition tells me it's possible because the actual component itself has no dynamic or interactive elements. It just needs to be completely re-rendered on the server. This is my first Next app and I pretty new to web development so I'm open to any suggestions, I might be thinking about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server components aren't interactive, but you can achieve what you need with the `searchParams` prop on `LottosPage`, and `useSearchParams` hook & `Link` component on the dropdown component.

A basic example:

**Dropdown component**

```js
'use client'

import Link from 'next/link'
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

const Dropdown = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()

  const createQueryString = (key: string, value: number | string) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams)
    params.set(key, String(value))

    return String(params)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Link href={`/lottos?${createQueryString('chainId', 100)}`}>
        Lotto 100
      </Link>
      <Link href={`/lottos?${createQueryString('chainId', 200)}`}>
        Lotto 200
      </Link>
      <Link href={`/lottos?${createQueryString('chainId', 300`}>
        Lotto 300
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dropdown
```

**Lottos page**

```js
interface Props {
  searchParams?: { chainId?: string }
}

const LottosPage = async ({ searchParams }: Props) => {
  const chainId = searchParams?.chainId ?? ''
  const games: Game[] = await getGames(chainId)

  // process and map games to LottoCards 
}

export default LottosPage
```

As stated in the [docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/page#searchparams-optional), using `searchParams` will opt the page into dynamic rendering at request time.

Comment: Thanks! I came across this but wasn't sure if it was the right approach. This completely removes the need for using the chainId state and the context provider since now client components can just access it using useSearchParams.get()